# Swift pushViewController() not working but present() is

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that has two storyboards: One for onboarding which displays a PageViewController with info about the app and the main view which shows displays a webview of the actual content.

I am trying to build in a sing out function to remove the data and bring them back to the Onboarding screen from where they will authenticate again. I have tried the following code after signing out but am not getting results.

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageControlViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true);
```

This code does nothing and the app continues as normal. Replacing the pushViewController() with present() does work but by showing a modal over the existing view.

`self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

My intention is to completely destroy the Main view and let the Onboarding view initiate a new version of the Main view.

Answer (score 0):

As your code rightly shows, `.pushViewController` is meaningful only if `self.navigationController` is not `nil`. But in your case, `self.navigationController` *is* `nil` — your view controller is not in a navigation interface. Hence pushing is impossible and nothing happens.

Comment: How can I switch to a new storyboard without using a navigationController?

Comment: This has nothing to do with switching storyboards. It has to do with where you are _now_, before the push. If you are not already in a navigation controller, the concept "push" has no meaning.

Comment: Are you saying the only way to achieve what I am trying to do would be within a navigationController?

Comment: But isn't a NavigationController meant to only be used within one storyboard?

Comment: Sorry I'm just not understanding how that's helpful. Everything I've read about navigation controllers indicates that it is meant for use in a single storyboard. I have two separate storyboards. I've found workarounds that involve using button segues to transition storyboards but my app resides in a web view so I cannot use them. What are you actually suggesting that I do?

Comment: The app is in a WKWebView. So none of the of the functionality is running on the device but on a server elsewhere so I can't use any of the native segues to transition between views. Can you give me an idea of how you would transition between two views programmatically?

Comment: I don't believe the web app is relevant. I'm just trying to transition between two view. controllers programatically.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you just try doing what I said. In the main storyboard, select the main view controller and choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. When you do, your code will start working, because now there is a navigation controller.